# Best way to access MS SQL DB behind a firewall

Tags: java, hibernate, security, jpa, jdbc

I have a multi-tenant app needing to access a customer-provided database residing behind a firewall, without requiring the user to open ports, etc. If we write this ourselves, we're thinking the path from our app to the customer's database would be:

1. Some sort of broker/proxy-capable data abstraction layer (Hibernate, JPA, etc)
2. JMS to communicate to software somewhere behind the customer firewall
3. The server side of #1
4. JDBC to the customer's database

Is this a better approach than simply running JDBC over SSH or VPN? Can anyone recommend existing open-source solutions that might do what we want?

Thanks! :)

Comment: An update...We still haven't found a perfect solution, but we're using a client-side appliance with OpenVPN and NAT that establishes a secure connection to the server. When the VPN connects, we're able to connect via JDBC to the database behind his firewall, but this seems like a fairly fragile approach.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a [SSL connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879949%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), so you can use any data access technology:

- JDBC
- JPA

You only need to configure a secure connection URL:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
jdbc:sqlserver://system:port;databaseName=myDb;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
</property>
```

Comment: If the target database is behind a firewall, how would the connection (SSL or otherwise) get through? Seems to us that to be firewall friendly, the connection needs to travel outbound from the database side, not inbound from the client. Yes?

Comment: You either install a server-side component on the customer site or the client has to open a port for your IP only. The port will require authentication so that's why I suggested SSL with certificates.

Comment: Yes - we're looking for the "server-side component" you mention...we're hoping there's a standard broker of some sort we can use in this configuration. Unfortunately, even though it's easy, JDBC with an open firewall port doesn't meet our requirements.